# Get the xml below root level through XQuery

Tags: sql-server-2008, xquery-sql

I have an XML as below stored in a table.

```
  `<Customer>
     <Name>
     <FName>Mark</FName>
     <MName>A</MName>
     <LName>Antomy</LName>
    </Name>
   <Address>
    <Street>Clare</Street>
   <City>Clarkson</City>
  </Address>
 </Customer> `
```

I want to select everything except the root node.

```
 `<Name>
    <FName>Mark</FName>
    <MName>A</MName>
    <LName>Antomy</LName>
 </Name>
<Address>
  <Street>Clare</Street>
  <City>Clarkson</City>
</Address>`
```

There are two parallel levels below root. I am unable to get them both in a single query.
Can it can be achieved through XQuery.
Thanks in advance.

Edit : removed an extra `enter code here` lurking in the xml.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.query()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx) with a wildcard:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (X XML);
INSERT @T (X) VALUES ('<Customer>
     <Name>
     <FName>Mark</FName>`enter code here`
     <MName>A</MName>
     <LName>Antomy</LName>
    </Name>
   <Address>
    <Street>Clare</Street>
   <City>Clarkson</City>
  </Address>
 </Customer>');

 SELECT X.query('/Customer/*')
 FROM   @T;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I was missing the wildcard.